# Understanding the 'void' type error in this scenario?

Tags: java

I feel so close yet so far!

```
/**
 * A program that accepts and int input through 2 command line arguments then,
 * calculates and prints  all the prime numbers up to that integer
 */

public class Primes {


   /**
   * Main method takes in 2 command line arguments  and calls
    * necessary algorithm
    * 
    * @param args command line arguments
    */
  public static void main(String[]args) {

  int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  int n = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

  for(;args.length < 2;) {

     if(a == 1){
        System.out.println(algorithmOne(n));
        /* }
           else if(a == 2) {
           //reference to method
           }
           else{ //reference to method
           }*/
     }


     System.err.println(timeTaken());
  }
 }


  /**Algorithm 1 method
   *
   *
   */
  public static boolean algorithmOne(int n) {

     for(int m = 2; m < n; m++) {
        if(n%i == 0)
           return false;
     }
     return true;
  }




  /**
   * Method works out time taken to perform an algorithm
   *
   * 
   */
  public static void timeTaken() {

     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     long time = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        time += i;
     }

     long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println(endTime - startTime); //prints time taken
  }
}
```

This is what I have written so far.

The error I get is 'void' type not allowed here, which I researched and learnt that: I am using a method that does not return a value in a place where a value is required such as the right side of an equal sign or a parameter to another method.

The thing is, I don't see exactly where that applies in my code!
Also, I have a feeling more errors are going to pop up after I fix this one, so any foresight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Which line does the error message correspond to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You call:

```
 System.err.println(timeTaken());
```

When:

```
public static void timeTaken() {
```

So what do you expect to print? `timeTaken` returns no value.

What you can do is return a value on `timeTaken`:

```
  public static long timeTaken() {

     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     long time = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        time += i;
     }

     long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     long diff = endTime - startTime;
     System.out.println(diff ); //prints time taken
     return diff;
  }
```

But be aware that you print the value twice (both inside `timeTaken` and its returned value).

Comment: I think the return type (void) is being the hassle, so I exchanged it for long. Does this sound like an acceptable alternative?

Comment: Yes. I also suggest to remove the printing inside `timeTaken`.

Comment: May I ask for your help once more? I altered the printing inside timeTaken to return, and it compiled perfectly. However, when I try run it in a terminal like this: java -jar Primes.jar 1 17, it returns nothing! Would you have any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 5):

This happens in the printing of TimeTaken():

```
System.err.println(timeTaken());
```

You're trying to print something that is void. `println` (naturally) does noe have an overloading that accepts void.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `timeTaken()` in `System.out.println()`. It is incorrect because `System.out.println()` needs to get an argument or more, and since your method doesn't return anything, you are receiving an error.

You just need to call `timeTaken()` (without `System.out.println()`). It will print the difference you are calculating insde because you are already printing it inside the method:

instead of:

```
System.out.println(timetaken());
```

use:

```
timetaken();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.err.println(timeTaken());
```

You must be getting error here:You are calling `System.err.println(timeTaken());` and your method is not returning anything i.e. `void`. So your method return type must be there. 
Or you call that method this way.

```
timeTaken()
```

Answer (score 3):

You method timeTaken() doesn't return a value, but you try to use the return value in the line:

```
System.err.println(""+timeTaken());
```

either let it return a string to print to the console, or just call the method.

Answer (score 3):

You would better code in Java with a IDE. eclipse, netbeans etc.

Answer (score 3):

Change your method return type to `long` and add `return` statement at the end of the method. So you won't get error in the line `System.err.println(timeTaken());`
In your code, `timeTaken()` method is sending `void` value to the `System.err.println(..)`, and in JAVA there is no such specification/design to send `void` to any method parameter. That is why it is throwing compiler error at line `System.err.println(timeTaken());`

```
/**
   * Method works out time taken to perform an algorithm
   *
   * 
   */
  public static long timeTaken() {

     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     long time = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        time += i;
     }

     long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
     System.out.println(totalTime); //prints time taken
     return totalTime;

  }
```